# How to post a map of string and list with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send a Map of string and list which is like:

```
Map<String, List<int>> results = {
  "tags": [5 , 10]
}
```

```
  Object headers = {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer ${accessToken}",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  };
```

and I post that like this:

```
  post() {
    return http
        .post("$resource/$baseName/$id$query",
            headers: headers,
            body: results ,
            )
        .then((http.Response response) {
        return json.decode(response.body);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }
```

and I got this error:

```
type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

also I guess that I should send

```
Map<String,String>
```

but I have

```
Map<String, List<int>>
```

I try many things but  am also new to flutter so I got confusing a lot 
Thanks if someone can help me .
EDIT:

i try with dio

```
try {
      Response response =
          await Dio().post("$resource/$baseName/$id$query", data: {
        'tags': [1, 2]
      },
      options: Options(headers: headers)
      );
      print(response);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create this map?

Wouldn't it be possible to start a .toString in the list?

Note: I suggest using the Dio plugin, it makes it much easier to work with requests in webServices, in my opinion of course!

Take a look here: https://pub.dev/packages/dio

```js
    
    Map<String, List<int>> results = {
       "tags": [5 , 10]
    }

    var dio = Dio();
    FormData data = FormData();

    final local = '$baseName/$id$query'

    dio.options.baseUrl = source;
    
    data.add('tags', results.toString);


    try{

      final response = await dio.post(local, data: data, options: Options(
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: ResponseType.json
      ));

      final body = jsonDecode(response.data);
      print(body);

    }catch(e){
      print(e);
      return e;
    }
```

Comment: thanks and I take a look at dio package but I don't know for example how to set the header and ... , because I am new to flutter and programming , can you write above code with dio package that I am replace it in my code please!!!

Comment: Have you tried to suggest a colleague above?

I believe that is what you need, if it does not work try the way I edited in my answer. Along with the way I work with Dio().

Answer (score 3):

Are you encoding your data when you send it? Try encoding your data before sending it. You specify your header to accept application/json, but you might not be sending json.

See: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html

```
import 'dart:convert';

 Map<String, List<int>> results = {
  "tags": [5 , 10]
};

  final encodedResults = jsonEncode(results); // send these encoded results.
```

Comment: This one fixed my problem :)